# Can anyone explain the average case in insertion sort?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, sorting

I am not sure if this question is off topic or not but a question like this has been asked on this site before - [Insertion sort proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409408/insertion-sort-proof)

Here is an example of insertion sort running a on a set of data
https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/13wi/lectures/02-25/19-sorting2-select-insert-shell.pdf

[image]

Here is the instructor's runtime proofs for the different cases (slide 10)
[image]

Can anyone explain the intuition behind the i/2 in average case? I get worst case(number of comparisons = element number) and the best case(everything in order, 1 comparison per element).

Comment: I don't know what insertion algorithm was used, but a "smart" algorithm doing binary search on the sorted portion would give a $\log i$-term in the sum...

Comment: @AlexR There are two standard versions: either you use an array, but then the cost comes from _moving other elements_ so that there is some space where you can insert your new element; or a list, the moving cost is constant, but _searching_ is linear, because you cannot "jump", you have to go sequentially. Of course there are ways around that, but then we are speaking about a different sorting algorithm (e.g. a heapsort if you insert your elements into a heap).

Comment: @dtldarek I agree with your point, but the slides estimate _the comparisons needed_, not the _moves needed_.

Comment: @AlexR Foolish of me to speak without looking at the slides. I agree with your point $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the slides I noticed the insertion sort *implementation* discussed here is actually sub-optimal: An element is swapped into place in a bubble-sort like manner.
Since the sorted list at step $i$ has $i$ elements, the average number of comparisons (= swaps - 1) needed to sort the $i+1$-st element into place is
$$\frac12(1_{\text{element is in place}} + i_{\text{element is smallest yet}})$$
So actually the correct average case estimate would be
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \frac{i+1}2 = \frac{(N-1)N}4 + \frac{N-1}2 = \frac{(N-1)(N+2)}{4}$$
But this is also $\mathcal O(n^2)$ so that's a minor mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The intuition relies on the fact that for every position in the array on an average half the elements are greater than the number in that position, and hence they will contribute to a comparison.